# Documentation For Oracle Cast Operation

Tags: json, oracle, casting

I am working on enabling [pljson](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson) to work with oracle 9i. The lexor for parsing pulls all of the json content to array's (which is an UDT that holds a nested table of base types, objects and arrays) , objects(which is a UDT which holds base types, objects and nested tables )  and base types. I have confirmed the lexor is converting the objects correctly. However, when I go to print the types the lexor has found I run into an error.

There appears to be an issue with records in a nested table, the second record(and any following records) in the tables shows up in the list but when i try to print the entire table, the second record's objects appear to be null.

I suspect the issue is casting or memory management in oracle 10G vs oracle 9i (because to print an object it has to be cast from its type to a JSON value). I haven't seen any changes in the oracle versions that would cause the second object's objects in nested tables to be null.

Can anyone explain the difference in 9i and 10G that could cause my nested table to have null records for the second row(and beyond) when casted ?

All of my code works has been tested in 11G (the docs for the program indicate 10G should be supported though..The only changes I have made to the core libraries is in adding a regex like sudo function in the lexor in order to support parsing)..

EDIT:
So the function was actually a reference to a type..for some reason the developer named it cast, and it was reference a variable of sys.anydata type..

EDIT:
I have narrowed the error down to the loading an object using getobject from sys.anydata .  Yet I don't see any changes that happen to that with Oracle 10G..I'm not sure whats wrong with the get object..it works on the first object but not the second object...

Edit:
I haven't done testing to confirm this so its just conjecture, if anyone can provide docs for it I would accept there answer ..but I suspect the issue I'm having is because sys.anydata.convertobject does not implicitly convert collections in 9i.. I think this behavior changed in 10g.. Meaning I need to call create anydata and fill it with convertobject and convertcollection anywhere that I have objects with collections..